# Get rid of White background in progressbar

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

I am following [this](http://vbcity.com/blogs/xtab/archive/2009/11/24/wpf-controltemplates-creating-a-non-rectangular-progressbar.aspx) tutorial to give a custom look to the progress bar. I have got the exact same look of the ProgressBar as shown in the tutorial. Still I post the image:

[image]

Can you see those white vertical bars in Indicator part of ProgressBar? I would like to get rid of them. In short I want a plain indicator.

Initially I thought that these bars are coming from Luna theme. So, I tried to replace that theme with the below mentioned themes one by one: AeroLight, Classic, Royale.

I tried above mentioned themes as only those themes contains a definition for ProgressBarBrushConverter class.

But I don't get any changes in the output.

So, I tried Aero theme but there I watched that Aero does not contain a definition for ProgressBarBrushConverter.

Code:

```
<Window x:Class="CurvyPB"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Luna"   
        Title="Curved ProgressBar" Height="400" Width="500">

    <Window.Resources>

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="PBCurvy" TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">

            <Grid>

                <Path x:Name="PART_Track" Stroke="{StaticResource BlueGreenRed}" StrokeThickness="5" 
                      Data="F1 M46.802502,0.50000018 C59.803562,0.50000006 71.553123,3.7052743 79.942001, 8.9014616 C88.330879,3.7052746 100.08044,0.5 113.0815,0.50000018 C125.92575, 0.5 137.54851,3.6284194 145.9305,8.6908474 C154.3125,3.6284194 165.93524, 0.50000006 178.7795,0.50000018 C204.35167,0.5 225.082,12.900593 225.082, 28.1975 C225.082,43.494408 204.35167,55.895 178.7795,55.895 C165.93524, 55.895 154.3125,52.766582 145.9305,47.704151 C137.54851,52.766582 125.92575, 55.895 113.0815,55.895 C100.08044,55.895 88.330879,52.689728 79.942001, 47.493538 C71.553123,52.689728 59.803562,55.895 46.802502,55.895 21.230335, 55.895 0.5,43.494408 0.5,28.1975 0.5,12.900593 21.230335,0.5 46.802502, 0.50000018 z"
                      Stretch="Fill">

                    <Path.Fill>
                        <MultiBinding>
                            <MultiBinding.Converter>
                                <converter:ProgressBarBrushConverter />
                            </MultiBinding.Converter>
                            <Binding Path="Foreground" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" />
                            <Binding Path="IsIndeterminate" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" />
                            <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="PART_Indicator" />
                            <Binding Path="ActualHeight" ElementName="PART_Indicator" />
                            <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="PART_Track" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Path.Fill>

                </Path>

                <Decorator x:Name="PART_Indicator" />

            </Grid>

        </ControlTemplate>

    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ProgressBar x:Name="CurvyPB" Width="300" Height="60" Template="{StaticResource PBCurvy}" />
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

In code-behind (just for testing):

```
Private Sub CurvyPB_Loaded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded

    Dim a As New DoubleAnimation
    a.From = 0
    a.To = 100
    a.Duration = New TimeSpan(0, 0, 8)

    CurvyPB.BeginAnimation(ProgressBar.ValueProperty, a)

End Sub
```

Comment: Add the relevant code here, in case that link changes. An SO question should stand on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of the converter is available [here](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/wpf/src/Themes/Shared/Microsoft/Windows/Themes/ProgressBarBrushConverter@cs/1305600/ProgressBarBrushConverter@cs). The copyright says for reference use only.

Basically what you need to change for this particularly ugly progressbar to fill without gaps is just this line:

```
double blockGap = 0.0; // <-- was 2.0
```

[image]

EDIT: Added `GuidelineSet` to prevent pixel snapping gaps (see comments).

The whole converter:

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// File: ProgressBarBrushConverter.cs
//
// Description:
// Converts a brush into a DrawingBrush used to display the "block" style
// progress bar
//
// History:
//  06/28/2004 - t-sergin - Created
//
// Copyright (C) 2004,2005 by Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
//
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;

using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;


namespace Microsoft.Windows.Themes
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The ProgressBarBrushConverter class
    /// </summary>
    public class ProgressBarBrushConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///      Creates the brush for the ProgressBar
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="values">ForegroundBrush, IsIndeterminate, Indicator Width, Indicator Height, Track Width
        /// <param name="targetType">
        /// <param name="parameter">
        /// <param name="culture">
        /// <returns>Brush for the ProgressBar</returns>
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            //
            // Parameter Validation
            //
            Type doubleType = typeof(double);
            if (values == null ||
                (values.Length != 5) ||
                (values[0] == null) ||
                (values[1] == null) ||
                (values[2] == null) ||
                (values[3] == null) ||
                (values[4] == null) ||
                !typeof(Brush).IsAssignableFrom(values[0].GetType()) ||
                !typeof(bool).IsAssignableFrom(values[1].GetType()) ||
                !doubleType.IsAssignableFrom(values[2].GetType()) ||
                !doubleType.IsAssignableFrom(values[3].GetType()) ||
                !doubleType.IsAssignableFrom(values[4].GetType()))
            {
                return null;
            }

            // Conversion

            Brush brush = (Brush)values[0];
            bool isIndeterminate = (bool)values[1];
            double width = (double)values[2];
            double height = (double)values[3];
            double trackWidth = (double)values[4];

            // if an invalid height, return a null brush
            if (width <= 0.0 || Double.IsInfinity(width) || Double.IsNaN(width) ||
                height <= 0.0 || Double.IsInfinity(height) || Double.IsNaN(height))
            {
                return null;
            }

            DrawingBrush newBrush = new DrawingBrush();

            // Set the viewport and viewbox to the size of the progress region
            newBrush.Viewport = newBrush.Viewbox = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);
            newBrush.ViewportUnits = newBrush.ViewboxUnits = BrushMappingMode.Absolute;

            newBrush.TileMode = TileMode.None;
            newBrush.Stretch = Stretch.None;

            DrawingGroup myDrawing = new DrawingGroup();
            DrawingContext myDrawingContext = myDrawing.Open();

            double drawnWidth = 0.0; // The total width drawn to the brush so far

            double blockWidth = 6.0;
            double blockGap = 0.0; // <-- was 2.0
            double blockTotal = blockWidth + blockGap;

            // For the indeterminate case, just draw a portion of the width
            // And animate the brush
            if (isIndeterminate)
            {
                int blocks = (int)Math.Ceiling(width / blockTotal);

                // The left (X) starting point of the brush
                double left = -blocks * blockTotal;

                // Only draw 30% of the blocks
                double indeterminateWidth = width * .3;

                // Generate the brush so it wraps correctly
                // The brush is larger than the rectangle to fill like so:
                //                +-------------+
                // [] [] [] __ __ |[] [] [] __ _|
                //                +-------------+
                // Translate Brush =>>
                // To have the marquee line up on the left as the blocks are scrolled off to the right
                // we need to have the second set of blocks offset from the first by the width of the rect
                newBrush.Viewport = newBrush.Viewbox = new Rect(left, 0, indeterminateWidth - left, height);

                // Add an animated translate transfrom
                TranslateTransform translation = new TranslateTransform();

                double milliseconds = blocks * 100; // 100 milliseconds on each position

                DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames animation = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
                animation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(milliseconds));  // Repeat every 3 seconds
                animation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;

                // Add a keyframe to translate by each block
                for (int i = 1; i <= blocks; i++)
                {
                    double x = i * blockTotal;
                    animation.KeyFrames.Add(new DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame(x, KeyTime.Uniform));
                }

                // Set the animation to the XProperty
                translation.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, animation);

                // Set the animated translation on the brush
                newBrush.Transform = translation;

                // Draw the Blocks to the left of the brush that are translated into view
                // during the animation

                // While able to draw complete blocks,
                while ((drawnWidth + blockWidth) < indeterminateWidth)
                {
                    // Draw a block
                    myDrawingContext.DrawRectangle(brush, null, new Rect(left + drawnWidth, 0, blockWidth, height));
                    drawnWidth += blockTotal;
                }

                width = indeterminateWidth; //only need to draw 30% of the blocks
                drawnWidth = 0.0; //reset drawn width and draw the left blocks
            }

            // Draw as many blocks
            // While able to draw complete blocks,
            while ((drawnWidth + blockWidth) < width)
            {
                var rect = new Rect(drawnWidth, 0, blockWidth, height);

                // Snap rect to pixels
                GuidelineSet guidelines = new GuidelineSet();
                guidelines.GuidelinesX.Add(rect.Left);
                guidelines.GuidelinesX.Add(rect.Right);
                guidelines.GuidelinesY.Add(rect.Top);
                guidelines.GuidelinesY.Add(rect.Bottom);

                myDrawingContext.PushGuidelineSet(guidelines);

                // Draw a block
                myDrawingContext.DrawRectangle(brush, null, rect);
                drawnWidth += blockTotal;
            }

            double remainder = width - drawnWidth;
            // Draw portion of last block when ProgressBar is 100% (ie indicatorWidth == trackWidth)
            if (!isIndeterminate && remainder > 0.0 && Math.Abs(width - trackWidth) < 1.0e-5)
            {
                // Draw incomplete block to fill progress indicator area
                myDrawingContext.DrawRectangle(brush, null, new Rect(drawnWidth, 0, remainder, height));
            }

            myDrawingContext.Close();
            newBrush.Drawing = myDrawing;

            return newBrush;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Not Supported
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">value, as produced by target
        /// <param name="targetTypes">target types
        /// <param name="parameter">converter parameter
        /// <param name="culture">culture information
        /// <returns>Nothing</returns>
        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

// File provided for Reference Use Only by Microsoft Corporation (c) 2007.
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

Comment: It worked really well but I saw very thin gap. So I set blockGap to -1.5 and now it looks great. I will award the bounty after 17 hours as per the rules of StackOverflow.com. Thanks for the great solution and it might help others in future as well.

Comment: I was able to reproduce those small gaps when I resize my window. I suppose this is a pixel snapping problem. Because the negative gap made me a bit uneasy;), I've looked for another solution. After adding a `GuidelineSet` to the `DrawingContext`, the problem disappeared for me.

Comment: I have tried the same by adding a GuidelineSet to the DrawingContext as you have done in the updated answer. But still if I keep blockGap = 0.0, I can still see small gaps.

Comment: Are you still using the exact code you showed in the question? Without being able to reproduce the gaps, I will have a hard time figuring out why you still see them. But if the negative margin is working for you, I guess that's ok.

Comment: No, I have changed the look of a progressbar and now I am using the converter that you specified. Yes, I get rid of those gaps if I set negative blockGap. Thanks for your hard work and time. And still if you find any new trick in future then please don't forget to post it here.